# How to solve this integral with trigonometric functions?

Tags: integration, trigonometry

How can I compute this integral manually?

$\int_{1}^{t} sin2(t-\tau)  cos2\tau  d\tau$

I've tried some substitutions, trigonometric manipulations, but still cannot reach a reasonable next step. Any hints?

Comment: hint: Fundamental Theorem of Calculus part 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hint; use

$\sin2(t-\tau)=\sin2t\cos2\tau-\cos2t\sin2\tau$

and [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FundamentalTheoremsofCalculus.html)